# plotly: Is it possible to adjust the camera field of view?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

For a 3D rendering in `plotly`, the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/3d-camera-controls/) explains the camera parameters `eye`, `center`, and `up`.

Some websites suggest that one can adjust the "zoom" by reducing the magnitude of `eye` --- but this just brings the viewpoint closer to the center.

I can't seem to find a way to adjust the field of view of the camera.

Essentially, is it possible to reproduce the [dolly-zoom effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's currently impossible to adjust the camera field of view.

I created a feature request at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/4005 :

> In https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plots/gl3d/scene.js, it uses `glPlot3d.createScene` and sets the options in `proto.prepareOptions`.
>
> In https://github.com/gl-vis/gl-plot3d/blob/master/scene.js#L179, the allowed options include the field-of-view parameter `fovy` (field-of-view in the vertical direction), which defaults to `Math.PI/4` (45 degrees).
>
> For 3D graphics, a 45-degree vertical field-of-view typically gives an exaggerated perspective.  It [corresponds to](https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/fov-tables) about a 28mm camera lens.
>
> It would be nice for `plotly.graph_objects.layout.scene.Camera` to include a `fovy` parameter (in radians).